# what is parsing ?And how we can implement it in j2me?

Tags: parsing, java-me

what is parsing ?And how we can implement it in j2me?

Answer (score 2):

> In computer science and linguistics, **parsing**, or, more formally, **syntactic analysis**, is the process of analyzing a text, made of a sequence of tokens (for example, words), to determine its grammatical structure with respect to a given (more or less) formal grammar.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is the process by which you scan a FILE (probably a text file) and do something with it. Depending on what you are trying to parse (XML, HTML, C code, Java code, anything...) you need to use a specific part of Java ME to do it.

Since I guess you are probably meaning XML parse, you can read [this](http://dsc.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/parsingxml/) document to do it.